# php code to retrieve image from /images

Tags: php, mysql, image

As you can see, I'm a beginner. I now have my search page retrieving the information from MYSQL but I have the images stored in public_html/images and have the code images/something.jpg stored in MYSQL. I've tried what I could find on the web but the best I've managed is to get a broken image. I've decided to give up after about three hours of searching and admit I need help. This is the last thing I tried. I know it's wrong because it doesn't work.

```
$img_url = "http://www.mysite.net/public_html/images/"; 
    { 
    echo '<img src="'.$img_url.$result['Images'].'" />'; 
    }
```

It seemed to make some sort of sense to me so I'd appreciate an explanation of why it is wrong. Thanks

Comment: have you tried `"http://www.mysite.net/public_html/" . $result['Images']`?

Comment: Isn't `public_html` internally the folder for the root? I think if you just do `http://www.mysite.net/images/something.jpg` that it will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `public_html` folder is the entry point to your web server on Apache servers and maps to a domain's root, i.e. some folder that is internally `/public_html/index.php` will be `http://example.org/index.php` externally.

Therefore, I believe your problem can be solved by removing `public_html` in your path:

```
$img_url = "http://www.mysite.net/images/"; 
    { 
      echo '<img src="'.$img_url.$result['Images'].'" />'; 
    }
```

Comment: Good grief. How could it be that simple? It works now!